# VS 2015 Remote Debugging doesn't go into CodeBehind file

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, remote-debugging

I'm  trying remote debug my website in the dev env and the breakpoints I'm creating in the CodeBehind file is not taking effect. I had already gone through some great SO answers on this topic and followed to the point. Initially it did not work (even after I did what was given in SO answers) but after sometime it worked only once and again not working. This is driving me insane and unable to find the cause of this random behavior. The below are the sequence of steps I followed for remote debugging

1. Assigned breakpoints in the CodeBehind file
2. Compiled the Solution in Debug Mode. Ensured that Debug -> Options -> General -> Require source files to exactly match the original version checkbox unchecked
3. Deployed my dll and pdb files of the concerned modules in the bin folder in the Dev environment
4. Loaded the symbols in Debug -> Options -> Symbols. Added my bin folder's location and clicked the Load all Symbols
5. Installed resources in my website (I'm using DNN)
6. Started my website
7. Attached the Solution with the website's process identified by its username

It worked only once but the rest of the time, it failed to stop at the breakpoints.

One more question I've is, for remote debugging, should I first assign breakpoints and then build in debug mode (so that my breakpoints are reflected in the pdb files) or I can assign breakpoints after the build and assign breakpoints on the go like in local debugging?

Comment: Do breakpoints work in source files that do not have a "design" view?

Comment: Yes. I was debugging my controller files and they were working just fine

Comment: Try this: 1. Start the site, attach VS debugging etc. 2. Update the html side of the page you wish to debug, just change some whitespace; 3. Do something that should hit your breakpoint

Answer (score 0):

This may be the same issue that is seen with debugging `Global.asax.cs`. From [this blog](http://wakeupandcode.com/hitting-breakpoints-in-global-asax/), the following steps can be taken:

1. Open the markup file in the code editor.
2. Make an inconsequential change in it (e.g. add a space inside a tag.)
3. Refresh the application in your browser.